# Android: Cannot get permission to publish_stream on Facebook application using socialauth-android

Tags: android, facebook, socialauth, facebook-permissions

I created a new application on Facebook for my Android application to share created images on Facebook. I need the permissions of Facebook `publish_stream`.

Facebook has recently changed their criteria to give `publish_stream`. They now require us to submit our application (with screen shots and description and APK) to get permission for `publish_stream`.

After review I got the following errors "`Your app cannot embed the Facebook Login dialog inside a custom web view. Utilize our native Facebook Login SDK, so that users do not need to login twice.`"

I do not know what to do about it because social auth always uses a custom web view to login the user on Facebook.